# Sending audio from phone to computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4, audio-recording, voicemail

I'm trying to record audio played by a phone by routing it through a computer running Windows 7. Specifically, I want to record voicemails playing from a Galaxy Note 4, which I was trying to do by playing the audio through the computer and recording with Audacity.

I have *one* male-to-male 3.5mm cable. By connecting that to my computer's mic jack and the phone's headphone jack, I can get a different phone (Galaxy S6) to play through my computer's speakers and can record like I want to, no problem. Also, plugging headphones into the Note 4, the audio plays perfectly through them. So, the cable works, and the phone's jack works.

But when I plug the cable into the Note 4, only half of the audio gets sent; I hear all the high-pitched parts through the computer's speakers, and all the low-pitched parts still come through the phone. Bizarre, to say the least. I would try using a different cable, but I only have the one, and it works fine on the other phone.

The voicemails are stored on my provider's server, not the phone, so I can't just copy them through USB, and trying to record them through the phone's speakers hurts the quality too much (lot of background noise here).

Ideally, I'd like to know what could be causing this strange problem and how to fix it, but any method of saving these voicemails will be enough. Can anyone help me out?